# Load same scripts in different iframes only once

Tags: jquery, performance, iframe, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have to optimize a website which has four different iframes. I *cannot* remove those iframes from the webpage. The iframes are from the same website but each of them loads a different webpage. For example, pagea.html, pageb.html, pagec.html, paged.html. The problem is that all these iframes are loading a jquery (1.8.1) file of their own. The original webpage itself is loading jquery (1.11.3). Is there any way I can avoid loading so many jquery files? I have three questions in my mind:

1. Load jQuery only once for page a,b,c and d. However, I don't know how to do that.
2. Avoid loading the jQuery on the original website and somehow use the jQuery loaded by the iframes. Is this possible?
3. Don't load jQuery in any of the iframes and only load it for the original website? Will the functionality in iframes stop working after that?

Comment: Try to move jQuery scripts to the main page.

Comment: @claudios They are loading from a third party website. i have no control over its source code.

Comment: @NeenaVivek Dont include jquery in pagea, b, c or d.  In your main page, create 4 frames. Load jquery in the main page. Once its loaded, asynchronously load the pages in the frames. This should work just fine.

Comment: @Teja, the issue is the OP has no control on the iframes to remove those scripts.

Comment: @Teja Thanks but I have no control over the source code of page a, b, c, d.

Comment: maybe try this in jquery like `$('iframe').contents().find('script').....`

Comment: @NeenaVivek um.. in that case, I guess its not possible. Coz, frames reside within the main page, and there is no way that the main page can use the jquery libraries loaded by the frames. To the main page, its just a frame, and it has no control over the libraries loaded by the frames

Comment: @claudios `$('iframe').contents().find('script').....` will not work because, the jquery in the main page starts loading asynchronously. It doesn't wait for the frames to load. 

More over, there may be some embedded native javascript, which will also have the same `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround is to use `sandbox` attribute. It will stop **all** javascripts running in particular iframes.

Ex:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" sandbox></iframe>
```

Now when you check you dev console, It says that javascripts are blocked. Now you can add those scripts inside your main page I guess.